# Linq, force an item to be first?

Tags: linq

I have a List<> of MyPersonObjects. The list is a list of people who I can assign something to. In this list, I include myself (As the task can be assigned to me - and usually is).

So, I want to make sure myself is at the top of the list. I know my personId, which is a property of my person object - so is there a way to order the list to make sure I am first, and then the rest, alphabetically by surname (which is another property of my object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just order the list by two separate criteria, the `OrderBy` will be the main sort order, if the values are equal (1 for all except you), `ThenBy` is used.

```
personList.OrderBy(x => x.Id == myId ? 0 : 1)
           .ThenBy(x => x.Surname);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to sort the list by surname with Linq and then remove yourself and put back at the first place:

```
var personList = db.MyPersonObjects.OrderBy(p => p.Surname).ToList();
var myself = personList.Single(p => p.Id == myselfId);
personList.Remove(myself);
personList.Insert(0, myself);
```

Or create a custom comparer `IComparer<MyPersonObject>` where the implementation is something like:

```
public class PersonCompaper : IComparer<MyPersonObject>
{
    private readonly int personId;

    public PersonCompaper(int personId)
    {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public int Compare(MyPersonObject x, MyPersonObject y)
    {
        if (x.Id == personId && y.Id == personId)
           return 0;
        if (x.Id == personId)
            return 1;
        if (y.Id == personId)
            return -1;            
        return string.Compare(x.Surname, y.Surname);
    }
}
```

Then you use it in the OrderBy

```
db.MyPersonObjects.OrderBy(p => p, new PersonCompaper(myselfId))
```